# Cakephp Associated table save

Tags: cakephp, save, linked-tables

Trying to save data from 2 models in associated table and extra data thats calculated from the column values in one model.

Subscription model:

```
class Subscription extends AppModel {
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('User');
}
```

User Model:

```
class User extends AppModel {
     public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Subscription','Role');
}
```

Joined with table subscriptions_users.

This is how im saving the post in the User Controller -> register method

```
    if($this->User->save($this->request->data))
    {
        // Add row to subscriptions_users
        $this->Subscription->User->create();

        // Format the request data for associated table subscriptions_users
        $data = $this->Subscription->handle_linked_subscription_request_data($this->request->data);

        // Save data to subscriptions_users
        $this->Subscription->User->saveAll($data);

        // Proceed to confirm
        $this->confirm($subdata_userdata);
    }
```

The function handle_linked_subscription_request_data in the subscription model:

```
public function handle_linked_subscription_request_data($data)
{

// Set array for data -> subscriptions_users
$linked_data = array();

if(isset($data) && !empty($data))
{
    // Get subscriptiondata to be used in calculations valid_until, terminate_at ...
    $this_subscription = $this->findById($data['User']['register_subscription_id']);
    if(isset($this_subscription) && !empty($this_subscription))
    {
        $linked_data['Subscription']['id'] = $data['User']['register_subscription_id'];
        $linked_data['User']['id'] = $data['User']['id'];

        // Add number of months from current date to binding ends
        $linked_data['valid_until'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 month"));
        $linked_data['activated'] = date('Y-m-d');
        $linked_data['binding_to'] =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+" . (int)$this_subscription['Subscription']['binding_months'] . " months"));

    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
else
{
    return false;
}

    unset($data);
    return $linked_data;
}
```

Id, user_id and subscription_id works and is inserted in the subscription_users "linking table" 
but the extra data:

```
$linked_data['valid_until'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 month"));
        $linked_data['activated'] = date('Y-m-d');
        $linked_data['binding_to'] =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+" . (int)$this_subscription['Subscription']['binding_months'] . " months"));
```

Just wont insert, i've tried different ways of inserting it by changing the array indexes.

And ideas how i could make this horrible solution better would be greatly appreciated :)

**Edit:**
Solved it by formatting array like this, but still so ugly.

```
        $linked_data['Subscription']['User'] = array(
                            'subscription_id' => $data['User']['register_subscription_id'],
                            'user_id' => $data['User']['id'],
                            'valid_until' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 month")),
                            'activated' => date('Y-m-d'),
                            'binding_to' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+" . (int)$this_subscription['Subscription']['binding_months'] . " months"))
            );
```